# How to automatically restart a service on failure in Linux

Tags: linux, service, socket

On Windows, you can set what should happen if/when a service fails.  Is there a standard way of achieving the same thing on Linux (CentOS in particular)?

A bigger part of my question is: how do you handle sockets that have been left open - for example in TIME_WAIT, FIN_WAIT1, etc states.

At the moment if the service I am developing crashes, I have to wait for the sockets to clear or change the listen port before I can then manually restart it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`monit` is a great way to monitor and restart services when they fail--and you'll probably end up using this for other essential services (such as Apache).  There's a [nice article on nixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-and-restart-linux-unix-service.html) detailing how to use this for services specifically, although `monit` itself has many more functions beyond this.

As for the socket aspect, @galraen answered this spot on.

Comment: It's a shame I have to decide which is _the_ answer.  I should have asked two seperate questions.  @gelraen your answer just ended my weeks of searching for a solution.  Thanks you *so* much!  @Redmumba thanks, Monit does look good!

Comment: Whichever one you decide to mark correct, definitely *upvote* @gelraen's answer.  Its spot on correct, and very informative.

Answer (score 39):

Only answering the service restart part. I came across Monit as well, but on CentOS 7 systemd takes care of all that for you. You just need to add these two lines to the .service file (if they're not there already):

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

Run `man systemd.service` for reference.

If you want to create a custom systemd service, it's pretty straightforward to write your own service file. See the example below, for a custom http server.

Start the editor with a new service file:

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/httpd.service
```

And add the following content, which you can edit as required:

```
[Unit]
Description=My httpd Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PERLLIB=/perl
ExecStart=/bin/httpd /etc/httpd.conf
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want it to start automatically on boot:

```
systemctl enable httpd
```

Tell systemd about the changes and start the service:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start httpd
```

And now you can see the status:

```
systemctl status httpd
```

There are  many options for `Restart`. The following is an excerpt from the *man* page:

> Restart=
>
> Configures whether the service shall be restarted when the
> service process exits, is killed, or a timeout is reached...
>
> Takes one of no, on-success, on-failure, on-abnormal, on-watchdog,
> on-abort, or always. If set to no (the default), the service will not
> be restarted. If set to on-success, it will be    restarted only when
> the service process exits cleanly. In this context, a clean exit means
> any of the following:
>
> •   exit code of 0;
>
> •   for types other than Type=oneshot, one of the signals SIGHUP,
> SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGPIPE;
>
> •   exit statuses and signals specified in SuccessExitStatus=.
>
> If set to on-failure, the service will be restarted when the process
> exits with a non-zero exit code, is terminated by a signal (including
> on core dump, but excluding the aforementioned four   signals), when an
> operation (such as service reload) times out, and when the configured
> watchdog timeout is triggered.

The restart can be tested by sending an appropriate signal to the application. See the manual at `man kill` for details.

Comment: Yes, exactly, `systemd`, the standard service manager on *most* popular distributions, can do that for you.

Comment: Also note that you can override anything in a system-installed service file by placing your own .conf file containing the lines to add/replace into e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/httpd.service.d`.

Comment: How do I test that this setting is actually working? I have just found that my previous setting `Restart=on-failure` `RestartSec=5s` did not restart my service ...

Comment: It could be that exit was not considered a failure by `systemd`, e.g. a clean exit code. To test, you could simulate a failure condition. Updated answer with additional details.

Answer (score 13):

You can call `setsockopt(2)` for listening socket with `SO_REUSEADDR`, so you will be able to `bind(2)` it again without waiting for expiring all connections. Another possibility: drop connections from kernel. FreeBSD have `tcpdrop` command for this, don't know about Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If your linux distro uses Upstart instead of SysV init, then the `respawn` keyword does this.

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#respawn

Comment: Thanks, this looks like just the thing, but unfortunately I'm stuck with SysV init.